# How to correcty reference the native dll in FSI e.g. 'Alea.CUDA.CT.Native.X86.B32.Windows'

Tags: aleagpu

I get the following exception when running Alea samples in F# interactive:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Alea.CUDA.CT.Native.X86.B32.Windows' is denied.

I am using Alea nugget packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can set two settings to get this work:

```
Alea.CUDA.Settings.Instance.Resource.AssemblyPath <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\..\packages\Alea.CUDA.2.x.x.x\private" // the folder where you alea cuda nupkg extracted
Alea.CUDA.Settings.Instance.Resource.Path <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\bin\release" // the folder where you have write permissions
```

Alea GPU will first search the natives in your `Resource.Path`, if the native (for your platform) is not yet there, Alea GPU will search resource assemblies from `Resource.AssemblyPath`, and extract the natives of your platform from the resource assembly to the resource working path.

By default, the resouce path is set to the base directory of your assembly, that is why you see it searchs in the Framework directory. For scripts, you need manually set them.

For more details please reference: http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/installation.html

Comment: Is there an update on this, the link seems to be broken now and i'm getting the same issue.

Comment: nvm found it :)